# window.location.href not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project and I have this script in a view :

```
 Yes : function () {
                        window.location.href = '~/Model/Selected';
                    },
```

When I click yes on popup it goes from:

> http://localhost:51234/Model/Details/

to

> http://localhost:51234/Model/Details/~/Model/Selected

I want it to go to :

> http://localhost:51234/Model/Selected/

How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: URLs are not Linux-bassed... there is no such thing as a "home directory"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the tilda.
`window.location.href = '/Model/Selected'`

If it starts with a slash, it's an absolute URL path appended to the hostname (http://localhost:51234 in your case). If it starts without a slash, it's relative and will be appended to the current URL path.

Answer (score 2):

then make it

```
Yes : function () {
   window.location.href = '/Model/Selected';
},
```